# UrbanCode udeploy NullPointerException in Run Groovy Script step

Tags: groovy, udeploy, urbancode

The same step was running fine for a couple of days and now getting this error. I've seen same error with UCD 6.1.1 too, then the code was able to run in UCD 6.2.1, but now fails again. What could be the issue?

```
plugin: Groovy, id: com.urbancode.air.plugin.Groovy, version: 6
plugin command: 'cmd' '/C' '"f:\apps\yyyy\agent\opt\groovy-1.8.8\bin\groovy -cp "f:\apps\yyyy\agent\var\plugins\com.urbancode.air.plugin.Groovy_6_c852a5128a51660ebc6986784c1163eb465daf6abf99d541d16108d08b14ab7e\classes;f:\apps\yyyy\agent\var\plugins\com.urbancode.air.plugin.Groovy_6_c852a5128a51660ebc6986784c1163eb465daf6abf99d541d16108d08b14ab7e\lib\plugins-util.jar" f:\apps\yyyy\agent\var\plugins\com.urbancode.air.plugin.Groovy_6_c852a5128a51660ebc6986784c1163eb465daf6abf99d541d16108d08b14ab7e\run_groovy_script.groovy F:\apps\yyyy\agent\var\temp\logs4673273741404342602\input.props F:\apps\yyyy\agent\var\temp\logs4673273741404342602\output.props"'
working directory: F:\apps\yyyy\agent\var\work\XH70_Javascripts
properties:
  PLUGIN_INPUT_PROPS=F:\apps\yyyy\agent\var\temp\logs4673273741404342602\input.props
  PLUGIN_OUTPUT_PROPS=F:\apps\yyyy\agent\var\temp\logs4673273741404342602\output.props
  groovyHome=f:\apps\yyyy\agent\opt\groovy-1.8.8
  scriptBody=import groovy.io.FileType
def currentDir = new File('.')
def files = []
currentDir.eachFile(FileType.FILES) {
    if (it.name.endsWith(".zip")) {
        files << it.name - "-bin.zip"
    }
}

println files[0]
outProps.put("zipfilename", files[0])
environment:
  AGENT_HOME=f:\apps\yyyy\agent
  AH_AUTH_TOKEN=****
  AH_WEB_URL=https://ucd.com:8443
  AUTH_TOKEN=****
  CODESTATION_URL=https://ucd.com:20081
  CODESTATION_USE_PROXY=false
  DS_AUTH_TOKEN=****
  DS_SYSTEM_ENCODING=Cp437
  JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=Cp437 -Dconsole.encoding=Cp437
  PLUGIN_HOME=f:\apps\yyyy\agent\var\plugins\com.urbancode.air.plugin.Groovy_6_c852a5128a51660ebc6986784c1163eb465daf6abf99d541d16108d08b14ab7e
  PROXY_HOST=ucd.com
  PROXY_PORT=20080
  UD_DIALOGUE_ID=b9521caf-6399-4455-a8e4-7e79bc3c95b2
  WE_ACTIVITY_ID=f819fba0-4800-4c87-9e29-5efa3698fe76
================================================================================

Running Groovy Script
command: f:\apps\yyyy\agent\opt\groovy-1.8.8\bin\groovy.bat C:\Windows\TEMP\groovy_script_8111838756530262064.groovy F:\apps\yyyy\agent\var\temp\logs4673273741404342602\input.props F:\apps\yyyy\agent\var\temp\logs4673273741404342602\output.props
null
Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java_util_Map$put.call(Unknown Source)
    at groovy_script_8111838756530262064.run(groovy_script_8111838756530262064.groovy:26)
Caught: com.urbancode.air.ExitCodeException: Command failed with exit code: 1
com.urbancode.air.ExitCodeException: Command failed with exit code: 1
    at com.urbancode.air.CommandHelper.runCommand(CommandHelper.groovy:195)
    at com.urbancode.air.CommandHelper$runCommand$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.urbancode.air.CommandHelper.runCommand(CommandHelper.groovy:121)
    at com.urbancode.air.CommandHelper$runCommand.call(Unknown Source)
    at run_groovy_script.run(run_groovy_script.groovy:64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that `currentDir.eachFile()` isn't returning any files, so `files[0]` is null.